# отцентрировать два блока из пяти

Tags: css3, html5

http://joxi.ru/V2VNPOZHx08gw2
разметка на бутстрапе. надо сделать, что если два блока, то их надо делать по центру, а если три блока, то они остаются на всю ширину(как изначально и есть)

Comment: "разметка на бутстрапе"  это ни о чем не говорит, какие стили заданы для контейнера и для выравниваемых блоков?

Answer (score -1):

центрируйте когда и три, и два. Если их будет три, то по сути они все равно останутся на одном вместе; либо можете вручную прописать; либо, в случае если блоки заполняются автоматически, то проверять на js и также дописывать атрибуты в нужные блоки.